# combine KeyCode pressed and modifiers to get final KeyCode

Tags: java, keyboard, keyevent, keycode

I'm struggling to find any answrs online to this problem...

On my Italian Keyboard if I press `Shift+'` I get `?`.
In my `EventListener`, the `KeyEvent` only reports that the `'` button is being pressed and that the `Shift` is active. From this I can deduce that the character typed is `?`. On a French or American keyboard for example, this doesn't work. I'd have to make an edge case for every keyboard layout...

I'm looking for something like this:

```
int finalKeyCode = KeyEvent.getExtendedFinalKeyCode(e.getExtendedKeyCode(), e.getModifiersEx());
```

It seems intuitive to me that there would be a way to get/determine the actual final second layer code entered, from the first layer keycode and the active modifiers relative to the current keyboard layout.

Another example is `Shift+F10` which is used for the ContextMenu. In the KeyEvent I get either code `525` if the keyboard has a dedicated button, or code `121` and the `Shift` modifier enabled which requires me just to make another if statement or switch case.

Is there a way to convert the first layer keycode in a second layer keycode using the modifiers?
Do i really have to do it manually with a ton of custom ifs or switch cases?
Is there a good reason for this that I'm not seeing?

Also, I know there is the `e.getKeyChar() == '?'` but I'm really trying to use only the keycodes as seems only intuitive to me that this should not be impossible...